# mview is not getting updated althought mlog is getting updated

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I am new to oracle sql

I have created a sample table like

```
Create table tab1(
name varchar2(15) primary key,ID number
);
```

I have created mlog on it;

```
create materialized view log on tab1 with primary key;
```

Now I have created mview:

```
Create materialized view mv1 refresh fast as select * from tab1;
```

Now I have Inserted few values into tab1;

```
insert into tab1 values('value',1);
```

I have seen that the table tab1 and mlog are actually getting updated

```
select * from tab1;
select * from mlog$_tab1;
```

these queries show that the mlog and table tab1 are actually getting updated

However when I have queried

```
select * from mv1;
```

no rows are present is shown.

**Update:**

Find somewhere on net that I have to use `commit scn including new values` for auto fast refresh.

So I changed my query as

```
create materialized view log on tab1 with primary key,commit scn including new values;
```

When I have tried this query,I was thrown an error saying

```
ORA-00406: COMPATIBLE parameter needs to be 11.2.0.0.0 or greater
ORA-00722: Feature "MV log with commit scn".
```

So I have removed `commit scn` and added refresh fast on commit while creating the mview.
And commited the transaction.

Final queries:

```
create materialized view log on tab1 with primary key including new values;
Create materialized view mv1 refresh fast on commit as select * from tab1;
insert into tab1 values('value',1);
commit;
```

Now every thing seems to be working fine.
However can some one point out what might be the issues with using commit scn while creating mlog?

Thanks..

Comment: Two things: First the inserted data in tab1 will never get to the materialized view until the transaction is committed. Have you committed the insert? Second you should specify in the create materialized view statement how often it should refresh with something like `NEXT SYSDATE + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE`, otherwise it does not refresh until you manually call refresh.

Comment: You are not refreshing the mview.